# PyQt: How to add new tabs to QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtextedit

I need to add a new tab, but I am having problems. I want to add new tabs in the main window, and keep the methods of the class `Editor()`. I can do this without having to create the class `Editor()` but need it to be so. Sorry for my English.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Editor")
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.edit = Editor()

        newAc = QtGui.QAction('New', self)
        newAc.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newAc.triggered.connect(self.new_)

        menu = self.menuBar()
        filemenu = menu.addMenu('&File')
        filemenu.addAction(newAc)

        self.tab = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)


class Editor(QtGui.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)


    def new_(self):
        tab = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.tab.addTab(tab, 'Untitled')

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the same text on both (or more) tabs you can use the same `Editor` class, but if not, you need instantiate an `Editor` object for each tab.

Also your code have some problems:

1- You are handling the tabs inside `Editor` objects. Instead, you must handle tabs at `Main` level.

2- The "default" tab you're adding when you create the `Main` object do not have any related `QTextEdit` change:

```
self.tab = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)     # <---- tab without QTextEdit
```

add this:

```
self.tab = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
self.editor = Editor(self.tab)      # editor receives self.tab widget as parent.
self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)
```

also you will need define `Editor` class before `Main`.

3- `Main` object don't have any method called `new_`, Editor does. So the line:

```
newAc.triggered.connect(self.new_)
```

it's wrong.

So your code might look like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Editor(QtGui.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)


class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Editor")
        self.resize(640, 480)

        newAc = QtGui.QAction('New', self)
        newAc.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newAc.triggered.connect(self.new_)

        menu = self.menuBar()
        filemenu = menu.addMenu('&File')
        filemenu.addAction(newAc)

        self.tab = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)
        self.tab.addTab(Editor(), "New Text")

    def new_(self):
        self.tab.addTab(Editor(), "New text")


def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```